# How can I divide/split an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array here which has (30 values e.g.).And I displayed it on a div. I want to split them into 3parts and display them in a three separated div. How can I do this one?Here's my code:

```
 <div class="span4">
 <?php if($col):?>
 <?php foreach($col as $names):?>
 <label class="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk_distinct" class="check" 
 value="<?php echo $names->COLUMN_NAME;?>">
 <?php echo $names->COLUMN_NAME;?></label>
 <?php endforeach;?>
 <?php endif;?>
 </div>
```

It will display this one:

```
<div>
Checkbox1
Checkbox2
Checkbox3
Checkbox4
...
Checkbox30
</div>
```

I wanted it to look like this one:

```
<div1>          <div2>             <div3>        
Checkbox1       Checkbox11         Checkbox21
Checkbox2       Checkbox12         Checkbox22
Checkbox3       Checkbox13         Checkbox23
Checkbox4       Checkbox14         Checkbox24
Checkbox5       Checkbox15         Checkbox25
...             ...                ...
Checkbox10      Checkbox20         Checkbox30
</div>          </div>             </div>
```

Any Idea about this one?Beginner here..

Comment: Take a look at `array_slice`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Yes I already looked at it. Thanks for the response., I got an idea there.

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk) For example

```
$cols = array_chunk($col, 10, true);

foreach ($cols as $col)
    {
    echo '<div>';
    foreach ($col as $names)
        {
        echo '<label>'.$names->COLUMN_NAME.'</label>';
        }
    echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Wow!This one great! Works like a charm. Thanks for your reply @sectus.
I tested it already and worked as what I wanted to do.